# How to return matching sublists or empty list

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

How to return matching sublists or empty list

```
m1 = {{1, 0.5}, {2, 0.4}, {3, 0.1}};
m2 = {{1, 0.5}, {0, 0.4}, {0, 0.1}};
Commonest[Join[m1, m2]]
```

out:

```
{{1, 0.5}}
```

But it fails to return 0 or empty list as the lists do not match

```
m1 = {{1, 0.5}, {2, 0.4}, {3, 0.1}};
m2 = {{0, 0.5}, {0, 0.4}, {0, 0.1}};
Commonest[Join[m1, m2]]
```

out:

```
{{1, 0.5}, {2, 0.4}, {3, 0.1}, {0, 0.5}, {0, 0.4}, {0, 0.1}}
```

how to return empty list?

Comment: Perhaps `If[(c = Commonest[Join[m1, m2]]) === Join[m1, m2], {}, c]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intersection[m1,m2]
```

will deal with common elements and return "empty set" if no common elements.
More complex list structures may require modification.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

This are your lists to try on:

```
m1 = {{1, 0.5}, {2, 0.4}, {3, 0.1}};
m2 = {{1, 0.5}, {0, 0.4}, {0, 0.1}};
m3 = {{2, 0.5}, {0, 0.4}, {0, 0.1}};
m4 = {{1, 0.5}, {2, 0.4}, {0, 0.1}};
```

This is the function to do the job on one element:

```
f[x_] := Select[m1, #1 == x &];

    f[{1, 0.5}]

   (*  {{1, 0.5}} *)
```

This is how it works on the list:

```
Flatten[f /@ m2, 1]

(*  {{1, 0.5}} *)
```

then

```
Flatten[f /@ m4, 1] 

 (* {{1, 0.5}, {2, 0.4}}  *)
```

and

```
Flatten[f /@ m3, 1] 

 (*  {}  *)
```

Have fun.